# Git commit in Xcode always causes submodule changes to be committed

Tags: xcode, git, git-submodules

I have one Git repository that contains a git submodule. In Xcode 4.2.1 I edit a file in the main repository and a file in the submodule, then I press "alt-cmd c" to perform a commit. In the commit dialog I deselect the file in the submodule, and leave only the file in the main repository selected. If I then press commit, both files have been checked in when I would expect only the file in the main repository to have been checked in.

Does the Xcode Git integration not support using submodules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Xcode 4.3.2 this issue no longer seems to be present so it appears it was just a bug in the previous version of Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have the same issue with Xcode, my workaround is using the terminal for commiting the submodule directories. After that Xcode ables me to push to the remote server

for commiting using terminal write:

```
git commit -am "message"
```

then check that everything is ok with:

```
git status
```